# Using PaintEventHandler - Visual C++ (Studio 2010) Windows Forms Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

So, I am creating a Windows Forms Application in Visual C++ 2010, and I want to add an event to a text box. When the program loads, a letter A is printed onto the screen. When you enter the text box, the letter is supposed to turn red.

The name of the textbox is AngleA, and this is the code I have so far:

```
this->AngleA->Enter += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler(this, &Form1::AngleA_Enter);
//many lines later
this->Controls->Add(this->AngleA);
//many lines later
public: System::Void Form1::AngleA_Enter(System::Object^  sender, PaintEventArgs^  e) 
     {
         System::Drawing::Font^ textFontA = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial", 16);
         System::Drawing::SolidBrush^ textBrushA = gcnew System::Drawing::SolidBrush(Color::Red);
         e->Graphics->DrawString("A", textFontA, textBrushA, 300, 120);
     }
```

The original drawing of the letter happens in a separate function, here:

```
    public: virtual Void Form1::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ pe ) override
{
   Graphics^ g = pe->Graphics;

   System::Drawing::Font^ textFont = gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Times New Roman", 16);

   SolidBrush^ textBrushA = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Black);

   g->DrawString("A", textFont, textBrushA, 300, 120);

}
```

So, the drawing of the original letter works great, but every time I try to build the program with the Enter event, I get the following error:

```
error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::Enter::add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventHandler ^' to 'System::EventHandler ^'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available, or
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

It seems to me that the form1 object (default name for class in windows forms apps) will only accept an EventHandler parameter for the "this->AngleA->Enter += gcnew " and not PaintEventHandler, but I dont understand why. Is there any way to create an Enter event function that will allow me to paint after the program has already loaded, based on an event?

Thanks for the help, I hope I was clear in my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add a `PaintEventHandler` to the `Paint` event; not to the `Enter` event.

You probably want to add a normal `EventHandler` to the `Enter` event and call `Invalidate()` in the handler.

Comment: Ok I see. The thing is, i dont want to repaint the control itself, I want to paint a red letter A over the existing one, in a different part of the window. How do I define the region of the string "A" that I want to paint over?

Comment: In the `Paint` handler, you can draw whatever you want, and it will draw over the control.

Comment: I dont really get how the Invalidate() works I guess; Heres what Ive got:
`code`public: System::Void Form1::AngleA_Enter(System::Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)

  {

   Rectangle rectangle;
   rectangle.X = 250;
   rectangle.Y = 120;
   rectangle.Width = 30;
   rectangle.Height = 30;
   Invalidate(rectangle);
  }
Obviously this is nowhere near what I want. How do I use the invalidate() function the way youre referring to?

Comment: How about using InvokePaint()?

Comment: InvokePaint won't help.  `Invalidate` should work; use the debugger to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Im not getting any errors at all with the code posted above, its just that nothing happens. What I dont get is that all Ive done with Invalidate is paint a rectangle with unspecified color/style at a location. I havent even painted text. I dont understand how this works.

Comment: @Jon: `Invalidate` causes the control to repaint.  That raises the `Paint` event.  Do you have a child control at that location?

Comment: I have the  public: virtual Void Form1::OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ pe ) override showed above.

Comment: Do you have a child control over the place you're painting?

Comment: This program is a single dialog box, so I should have control over the entire program from any part, right? Sorry for being so troublesome, Im new to Windows programming. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: Do you have a control (such as a button or textbox) there?

Comment: Heres what it looks like (link to image)[link](http://i594.photobucket.com/albums/tt24/Mandalore93/textboxview.png)
The idea is that when you click or TAB into the text field, the letter turns red.

Comment: I have used a little workaround to make this work. Thanks for the help. If you could still explain to me how you intended it to work, that would be great, because this workaround is rather messy.